# Handling State changes between threads

Tags: multithreading, oop, design-patterns, concurrency

I have worker thread which needs to perform various tasks based on commands given by another thread (say a thread interacting with the user). The worker thread needs to perform the following functions,

a. Once started, the worker thread needs to wait for user thread to give a task.
b. Once a task is given, worker thread needs to keep performing the task unless told to do otherwise.
c. At any point in time, the user thread can ask the worker thread to stop (exit), pause, continue, pause and wait for another task etc.

I keep coming across this use case many times while working on multithreaded programs and often end up using complicated logic (lot of if/elses, semaphore signal/wait etc.)

So I am wondering if there is good design pattern for this use case?

Comment: This is really a very unusual case and not typical at all. Generally, if there's work you need to do, you do it. Having to stop, pause, continue, or wait is *very* unusual. I've written multi-threaded programs for more than a decade now and never had to do any of these things. (Other than wait for work when there's literally nothing to do at all, but that's part of your basic work dispatch mechanism and not something extra.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: I deal with these use cases in the App level where the user requests can come in any order. A good example would be a camera app: start app, start preview, pause preview, take picture, lock screen, exit app etc.

Comment: All those use cases involve stopping particular work from being done, not stopping threads. When you want to pause the preview, you don't care what thread is doing it or even whether a thread is doing it at that particular time. It's the previewing of work that you want to pause -- whether one thread or fifty threads are involved in that process.

Answer (score 1):

The [actor model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model) might be a good fit in these situations. I’m working on the [Akka toolkit](http://akka.io), you can read more about building software using actors in the [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/actor-systems.html). To give you some impression on how the worker entity you describe might look like, consider the following code (written in Scala, but should be descriptive by itself):

```scala
trait State
case object Idle extends State   // marker object for the no-work state
case object Active extends State // marker object for when there is work to do
case object Paused extends State // marker for when work is known but paused

class Worker extends Actor extends FSM[State, Option[Work]] {
  startWith(Idle, None) // start out with no work to do
  when(Idle) {
    case Event(DoWork(workPackage), _) =>
      self ! KickMe // message sent to this actor to make it perform some work
      goto(Active) using Some(workPackage)
  }
  when(Active) {
    case Event(KickMe, Some(work)) =>
      execute(work)
      self ! KickMe // this keeps the work going until told otherwise
      stay()
    case Event(Pause, _) =>
      goto(Paused)
  }
  when(Paused) {
    // KickMe messages are ignored in this state, leading to a pause
    case Event(Resume, _) =>
      self ! KickMe
      goto(Active)
  }
  whenUnhandled { // these cases apply in all three states
    case Event(Stop, _) =>
      stop()
    case Event(DropIt, _) =>
      goto(Idle) using None // zero out the current work package
  }

  def execute(work: Work) = ... // whatever there is to do
}
```

You can then interact with such a [state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) by sending it messages:

```scala
// initialize Akka
val system = ActorSystem("demo") 
// instantiate the actor, returning an ActorRef
val workerRef = system.actorOf(Props[Worker], name = "Fred")
// send the first work package to get it going
workerRef ! DoWork(new MyWork(...)) // whatever the work package
... // after some time
workerRef ! Pause
... // and then even later maybe
workerRef ! Resume
... // and finally
workerRef ! Stop
```

The implementation above is not 100% bullet proof (since I wanted to focus on demonstrating the general principle), and it is also not the only way of writing something like this in Akka. The important part is that you don’t manage threads explicitly, you only manage your actors, and Akka will take care to run them on threads and pass the messages safely between them. In case this looks interesting, feel free to inquire for more information on the [mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/akka-user).

Answer (score 0):

```
object thisLock;
bool paused;
bool exit;

void YourThread() {

    while (true)
    {

        lock (thisLock)
        {

            if (exit) return;

            while (paused)
                Monitor.Wait(thisLock);


        }

        //do some work
        //process one item
        //whatever

    }

}
```

to pause -

```
paused = true;
```

to unpause -

```
lock (thisLock)
{
    paused = false;
    Monitor.Pulse(thisLock);
}
```

to exit

```
exit = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic most probably complicates because you are trying to make a single entity do too much work (which results in O(N!) complexity).

If you make thread safety a policy (thread safe/unsafe queue, synchronization points, flags, etc.) along with other behavioral aspects then both worker and policies will be compact reusable Lego blocks of clean design.

Answer (score 0):

Here I post a header of one method - it helped me as a precondition to a while loop:

```
private static final boolean conditionMet (
    final boolean isEventDispatchThread    
    , final List<AWTEvent> pendingEvents
    , final AtomicBoolean isDefaultEventQueue
    , final AtomicBoolean isEventQueueChanging
    , final AtomicReference<DispatchableEventQueue> newEventQueue
    , final AtomicReference<ProgressMonitor> processMessageBlocking
    , final AtomicInteger actionsRemaining
    , final AtomicBoolean interruptAction
    , final AtomicReference<Tuple2<IAction, Throwable>> throwableWasThrownFromChain        
    , final ConcurrentHashMap<IAction, Boolean> valuesReadyToBeSetFromEDT
    , final ConcurrentHashMap<IAction, Boolean> valuesWasSetFromEDT
    , final ConcurrentHashMap<IAction, Boolean> onSwingReadyToBeRunFromEDT
    , final ConcurrentHashMap<IAction, Boolean> onSwingWasActuallyRunFromEDT
    , final FlexReference<Map<String, Object>> remoteRef        
) throws InterruptedException {
```

I may still wondering if that was a good design pattern, but by using a state machine or not, if you try to keep things simpler in one place (while), then its not that hard to get a bigger mess in a different place (condition). The middle way to me, is a programming on a higher level and taking for granted, all those timeouts, not availabilities and deaths.